Gazebo Harmonic - is it possible to dynamically change sensor parameters?
I'm looking for a way to dynamically modify lens parameters of WideAngleCamera in Gazebo Harmonic v 8.6.0. I know there was such a possibility in Gazebo Classic using gazebo/rendering/WideAngleCamera model in custom plugin, but currently I haven't found similar functionality in gz-sim.
Example of sdf WideAngleCamera code:
    <sensor name="wideangle_camera" type="wideanglecamera">
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>3.14</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>800</width>
          <height>600</height>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>100</far>
        </clip>
        <!-- A new section named `lens`. -->
        <lens>
          <!-- type element is mandatory -->
          <type>custom</type>
          <!-- manually defined mapping function r = c1*f*fun(theta/c2 + c3) -->
          <!-- More information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens#Mapping_function -->
          <custom_function>
            <c1>1.05</c1>
            <!-- linear scaling -->
            <c2>4</c2>
            <!-- angle scaling -->
            <f>1.0</f>
            <!-- one more scaling parameter -->
            <fun>tan</fun>
            <!-- one of sin,tan,id -->
          </custom_function>
          <!-- if it is set to `true` your horizontal FOV will ramain as defined -->
          <!-- othervise it depends on lens type and custom function, if there is one -->
          <scale_to_hfov>true</scale_to_hfov>
          <!-- clip everything that is outside of this angle -->
          <cutoff_angle>3.1415</cutoff_angle>
          <!-- resolution of the cubemap texture, the highter it is - the sharper is your image -->
          <env_texture_size>512</env_texture_size>
        </lens>
      </camera>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <update_rate>30</update_rate>
      <topic>wide_angle_camera</topic>
    </sensor>

In particular, I would like to tune c1, c2 parameters.
Does anybody know if there is such a possibility?

I had a quick look at the WideAngleCameraSensor and CameraSensor source code, and I don't see any means to update the camera parameters online (i.e. through a message or service call).
So the only current option seems to change the values in the SDF and reload the simulation.
I think it might be relatively straightforward to add this functionality though.  Without having looked into this in detail, I think it could be just a case of:

Creating a subscription for a CameraLens message (with the same Gazebo Node as the existing image publisher),
Ideally its topic should be configurable from the SDF, similar to here,
Have its callback call UpdateLensIntrinsicsAndProjection()

Alternatively, it should be possible to write a system plugin similar to the camera_video_recorder, which retrieves the camera entity from the ECM, retrieves the camera and calls methods on it.

Thanks! Looks like solution, I will try your approach

Great. If you get it to work, consider submitting it as a pull request. Generally such functional improvements are very much welcomed by the maintainers!
